# Concatenate the values of multiple arrays on VBA for Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to concatenate the elements of multiple arrays in a final array that will store the concatenation. The code will first need to loop and store the values from cells then concatenate the stored values.
From cells:

```
A 1 V
B 2 W
C 3 X
D 4 Y
E 5 Z
```

New array being:

```
A1V
B2V
C3X
D4Y
E5Z
```

Sample code:

```
sub Concatenation()
Dim CntCol_updated As Long, CntRow_updated As Long
With Worksheets("Sheet1")



    CntCol_updated = Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(1, 1).End(xlToRight)).Count
    CntRow_updated = Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, 2).End(xlDown)).Count

    Dim Largeur() As Variant
    Dim Série() As Variant
    Dim Diamètre() As Variant
    Dim Charge() As Variant
    Dim Concatenated_Array() As Variant


    Largeur = Range(Cells(1, 9), Cells(CntRow_updated, 9))
    Série = Range(Cells(1, 10), Cells(CntRow_updated, 10))
    Diamètre = Range(Cells(1, 11), Cells(CntRow_updated, 11))
    Charge = Range(Cells(1, 12), Cells(CntRow_updated, 12))


    ReDim Concatenated_Array(UBound(Largeur))
    For i = LBound(Largeur) To UBound(Largeur)
          Concatenated_Array = Largeur(i) & Série(i)  & Diamètre(i) & Charge(i)
    Next i


    Range("A28:A53").value = Concatenated_Array

end with
end sub
```

Comment: And what isn't working with your code?

Comment: "Run-time error '9': subscript out of range" at line "Concatenated_Array = Largeur(i) & Série(i)  & Diamètre(i) & Charge(i)". I can't figure out what is wrong since my knowledge in arrays is kind of limited still.

Comment: Largeur is a 2d array whereas concatenated is 1d. concatenated will also start at 0 whereas your other will start at 1.

Comment: `Concatenated_Array(i) = Largeur(i,1) & Série(i,1)  & Diamètre(i,1) & Charge(i,1)`.

Comment: … and `Range("A28").Resize(UBound(Concatenated_Array), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Concatenated_Array)
`

Comment: If you have Excel 2016+, you could just use the `CONCAT` or `TEXTJOIN` function on the worksheet.

Comment: with SJR and T.M. comments, the macro works beautifully!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read in ranges to an array you generate a 2d array with base 1. So, `Largeur` for example is 2d and starts at 1 whereas `Concatenated_Array`  is 1d and starts at 0.

Instead you could read the different ranges into one array, re-dimension to add another column at end, loop all rows in array and concatenate columns 1-4 and add to column 5. You can then access what you want from last column in array

```
Dim loopArray()
With ActiveSheet
    loopArray = .Range(.Cells(1, 9), .Cells(CntRow_updated, 12)).Value
End With
ReDim Preserve loopArray(1 To UBound(loopArray, 1), 1 To UBound(loopArray, 2) + 1) 'make space for concatenated column at end

For i = LBound(loopArray, 1) To UBound(loopArray, 1)
    loopArray(i, 5) = loopArray(i, 1) & loopArray(i, 3) & loopArray(i, 3) & loopArray(i, 4)
Next i
```